# Is "rondigi" for "rounding up" commonly understood?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

I found "rondigi" for round up, as in rounding up numbers, in Reta Vortaro. I'm not sure if I have ever heard it used before. Have you seen or heard this word used in this meaning?

Comment: As far as I understand from the definition in ReVo, it doesn’t seem to specify whether it means “rounding up” or “rounding down”, so I’m pretty sure it at least wouldn’t be understood to be explicitly rounding *up*. Maybe you could say “rondigi supren” to be more precise.

Comment: In the context I'm translating, I don't know if they're rounding up or down, so the ambiguity is welcome. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I would understand it immediately and I am pretty sure most people understand it correctly, especially if you specify that you round a number.